# Ubuntu 16.04: remove home encryption but leave whole disk encryption

Tags: encryption, home-directory, ecryptfs

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.02 server with full disk encryption, but also enabled home directory encryption which is now interfering with some other system functions. How can I disable home directory encryption system-wide without affecting whole disk encryption? I see instructions online for disabling home directory encryption, but they all end with uninstalling ecryptfs-utils & libecryptfs0 modules, and I don't know how that will impact whole disk encryption.

Comment: please actually read my question before dismissing it as a duplicate. that other question says to remove ecryptfs-utils and libecryptfs0 and I explicitly ask if that will impact whole disk encryption, which is different from home directory encryption, in case you don't understand what it is

Comment: @DavidFoerster please actually read my whole question; the other question says to remove ecryptfs-utils and libecryptfs0 and I explicitly ask if that will impact whole disk encryption

Comment: @qbi please actually read my whole question; the other question says to remove ecryptfs-utils and libecryptfs0 and I explicitly ask if that will impact whole disk encryption

Comment: @ParanoidPanda please actually read my whole question; the other question says to remove ecryptfs-utils and libecryptfs0 and I explicitly ask if that will impact whole disk encryption

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix please actually read my whole question; the other question says to remove ecryptfs-utils and libecryptfs0 and I explicitly ask if that will impact whole disk encryption

Comment: @Zanna please actually read my whole question; the other question says to remove ecryptfs-utils and libecryptfs0 and I explicitly ask if that will impact whole disk encryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go with Ubuntu used those tools for home directory encryption only 
 and uses LUKS for  whole drive encryption your drive will persist being encrypted with out those tools.

worry not just remove them and your whole drive will remain functional and encrypted

Think about it like this pre decryption at start-up you have no access to any files or tools with in that encrypted partition witch makes it impossible for LUKS to be dependent on them. LUKs uses side space to function before decryption.

I would recommend full backup of any important files before trying to remove the home directory encryption. You never know better be safe then sorry even if it's very unlikely.

Comment: you are correct. uninstall went without issue, no data lost. rebooted just fine.